# jQuery - .hover() fires on sub-elements

Tags: jquery, hover

I am trying to target the `<li>`s from a `<ul>` and give them a hover event.

Unfortunately the `<li>`s contain some other `<div>`s that are positioned outside the `<li>` itself.

The problem occurs that the .hover() event fires when I hover on the child `<div>`s since DOMwise they are children, even though design/geometry-wise the seem like a diffent element totally.

Is there any way, or any other event that I can use for when the cursor runs over the `<li>` itself and NONE of it's sub-elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for a style change?
If so try using CSS pseudo events instead of jQuery, e.g.:

```
li:hover
{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Alternatively, use e.stopPropagation(), e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent").click(function(){
        // do whatever;
    });
    $(".child").click(function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Unfortunately I don't think this works with hover, but it does with mouseover and mouseout, which is what hover basically uses.

Comment: 2nd one was a daysaver. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property to determine the originator of the event to achieve this:

```
$('li').hover(function (event) {
   if ($(this).is(event.target)) {
     // Your code here
  }
});
```

AFAIK there is nothing standard for this, since DOM elements need not necessarily have any size and the bubbling behaviour is generally desirable.

Comment: You don't have to use jquery for every thing.

    if(this === event.target)

is also valid.